# Minimize $xy$ over $x^2+y^2+z^2=7$ and $xy+xz+yz=4$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, optimization, lagrange-multiplier, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

> Let $x,$ $y,$ and $z$ be real numbers such that $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 7$ and $xy + xz + yz = 4.$ Find the smallest possible value of $xy.$

---

I used Cauchy to get $$(x^2+y^2+z^2)(1^2+1^2+1^2)\geq (x+y+z)^2$$ and $$(x^2+y^2+z^2)(y^2+z^2+x^2)\geq(xy+xz+yz)^2,$$ but this doesn't do much as both of the inequalities already work. :( Any guidance would be appreciated!!

Thanks in advance!!!

P.S. I've been given that this can be solved by Lagrange multipliers, but I haven't learned it yet. Hopefully, someone can give me hints on a method that doesn't involve Lagrange multipliers. :)

Comment: Have you tried Lagrange multipliers method?

Comment: I don't know how to use Lagrange multipliers. :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would start with noticing that

\begin{align*}
(x + y + z)^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2} + z^{2} + 2(xy + xz + yz) = 15
\end{align*}

Therefore $x + y + z = \pm\sqrt{15} =: k$. Better saying, $z = k - x - y$.

Then we arrive at the relation

\begin{align*}
xy + xz + yz & = xy + z(x + y)\\\\
& = xy + (k - (x + y))(x + y)\\\\
& = xy + k(x + y) - (x + y)^{2} = 4\\\\
& \Rightarrow xy = (x + y)^{2} - k(x + y) + 4 
\end{align*}

Let us make the change of variable $t = x + y$.

Then we are interested in the minimum value of the RHS above, which is given by $1/4$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
t^{2} - kt + 4 & = \left(t^{2} - kt + \frac{k^{2}}{4}\right) + 4 - \frac{k^{2}}{4}\\\\
& = \left(t - \frac{k}{2}\right)^{2} + 4 - \frac{15}{4} \geq \frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

Hence the minimum value of $xy$ satisfying the proposed constraints equals $1/4$.

Hopefully this helps !

**EDIT**

As an answer to the (well posed) comment of @RobPratt, we must show such value is attained.

Indeed, this is the case as the following system of equations show:
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
xy = \dfrac{1}{4}\\\\
x + y = \dfrac{\sqrt{15}}{2}
\end{cases} & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x = \dfrac{\sqrt{15} \mp \sqrt{11}}{4}\\\\
y = \dfrac{\sqrt{15} \pm \sqrt{11}}{4}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

as well as the following system of equations:

\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
xy = \dfrac{1}{4}\\\\
x + y = -\dfrac{\sqrt{15}}{2}
\end{cases} & \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x = -\dfrac{\sqrt{15} \mp \sqrt{11}}{4}\\\\
y = -\dfrac{\sqrt{15} \pm \sqrt{11}}{4}
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Comment: You have derived a lower bound but still need to show that it can be attained.

Comment: @RobPratt I have edited my answer and provided the corresponding solutions to the minimizing value.

Comment: Looks good. (+1)

Comment: Thanks! Also I think I might have thought of another method. Is it possible to use \begin{align*}
(x + y - z)^2 &= x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2xy - 2xz - 2yz \\
&= (x^2 + y^2 + z^2) + 4xy - 2(xy + xz + yz) \\
&= 7 + 4xy - 8 \\
&= 4xy - 1?
\end{align*}

Answer (score 3):

$x^2+y^2+z^2 = 7$ and $xy +xz + yz = 4$
implies
$x+y+z = \pm\sqrt{15}$
Now using the second equality that is given in the question, we get
$xy  =4 -(x+y)z = 4 -  (\pm\sqrt{15} - z)z$

- Case 1: When $x+y+z=\sqrt{15}$, minimising the right hand side with respect to $z$ gives $z = \frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}$. So, minimum value of $xy$ is $4 -  (\sqrt{15} - z)z= 4-\frac{15}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$.
- Case 2: When $x+y+z=-\sqrt{15}$, minimising the right hand side with respect to $z$ gives $z = -\frac{\sqrt{15}}{2}$. So, minimum value of $xy$ is $4 -  (-\sqrt{15} - z)z= 4-\frac{15}{4}=\frac{1}{4}$.

So the minimum value of $xy$ is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: As RobPratt mentioned above, you've showed that we have a lower bound. For it to truly be a minimum, you have to show that it can be attained.  $\quad$ Rest looks good.